# Is there any way to have project specific package settings in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I've installed JSMinifier via Sublime Text 2's package manager and I'd like to set the compiler settings for a specific project.

I can find how to set package specific settings, and I know how to do project specific settings, but is there any way to set project specific package settings?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, but with the DetectSyntax package. I don't want the settings for that package to leak from one project to others.

Comment: I have the same problem with a package I'm developing. I created an idea on Sublime's UserVoice, if you guys [vote and/or comment on it](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/118670-override-plugin-settings-per-project-via-sublime-project/) this may get added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try out [ProjectSpecific](http://bitbucket.org/klorenz/projectspecific) package from PackageControl. I just have added support for
project specific package settings.

Assume you want to turn on "console_log" for scope_hunter.sublime-settings for only
current project, then (after installing ProjectSpecific), add following lines to your 
.sublime-project file:

```
{
    ...
    "settings": {
        "project-specific": {
            "sublime-settings": {
                "scope_hunter": {
                    "console_log": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this some more? I'm attempting to get [jscs-formatter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSCS-Formatter) to run on save, but only for one project. [This is the relevant portion of my project file](https://gist.github.com/atuttle/89ce0ca679164673a22e), but it's not formatting on save. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This looks fantastic, but is there an equivalent of this for Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Hmm, apparently, the above syntax works by default in Sublime Text 3 (for some packages, at least; not sure if it works for all).

Answer (score 1):

Seems it cannot be done natively. The package must be programmed to use project specific files (like i.e. SFTP does), but this could be helpful: http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/sublime-text-2-beta-project-specific-settings/